# Choice of the most performant container (array)

Tags: c++

This is my little big question about containers, in particular, arrays.

I am writing a physics code that mainly manipulates a big (> 1 000 000) set of "particles" (with 6 `double` coordinates each). I am looking for the best way (in term of performance) to implement a class that will contain a container for these data and that will provide manipulation primitives for these data (e.g. instantiation, `operator[]`, etc.).

There are a few restrictions on how this set is used:

- its size is read from a configuration file and won't change during execution
- it can be viewed as a big two dimensional array of N (e.g. 1 000 000) lines and 6 columns (each one storing the coordinate in one dimension)
- the array is manipulated in a big loop, each "particle / line" is accessed and computation takes place with its coordinates, and the results are stored back for this particle, and so on for each particle, and so on for each iteration of the big loop.
- no new elements are added or deleted during the execution

First conclusion, as the access on the elements is essentially done by accessing each element one by one with `[]`, I think that I should use a normal dynamic array.

I have explored a few things, and I would like to have your opinion on the one that can give me the best performances.

As I understand there is no advantage to use a dynamically allocated array instead of a `std::vector`, so things like `double** array2d = new ..., loop of new, etc` are ruled out.

So is it a good idea to use `std::vector<double>` ?

If I use a `std::vector`, should I create a two dimensional array like `std::vector<std::vector<double> > my_array` that can be indexed like `my_array[i][j]`, or is it a bad idea and it would be better to use `std::vector<double> other_array` and acces it with `other_array[6*i+j]`.

Maybe this can gives better performance, especially as the number of columns is fixed and known from the beginning.

If you think that this is the best option, would it be possible to wrap this vector in a way that it can be accessed with a index operator defined as `other_array[i,j] // same as other_array[6*i+j]` without overhead (like function call at each access) ?

Another option, the one that I am using so far is to use Blitz, in particular `blitz::Array`:

```
typedef blitz::Array<double,TWO_DIMENSIONS> store_t;
store_t my_store;
```

Where my elements are accessed like that: `my_store(line, column);`.

I think there are not much advantage to use Blitz in my case because I am accessing each element one by one and that Blitz would be interesting if I was using operations directly on array (like matrix multiplication) which I am not.

Do you think that Blitz is OK, or is it useless in my case ?

These are the possibilities I have considered so far, but maybe the best one I still another one, so don't hesitate to suggest me other things.

Thanks a lot for your help on this problem !

**Edit:**

From the very interesting answers and comments bellow a good solution seems to be the following:

- Use a structure `particle` (containing 6 doubles) or a static array of 6 doubles (this avoid the use of two dimensional dynamic arrays)
- Use a `vector` or a `deque` of this `particle` structure or array. It is then good to traverse them with iterators, and that will allow to change from one to another later.

In addition I can also use a `Blitz::TinyVector<double,6>` instead of a structure.

Comment: just curious: what kind of physics are you modeling?

Comment: You can look at this https://ab-project-mte.web.cern.ch/AB-Project-MTE/, and this https://ab-project-mte.web.cern.ch/AB-Project-MTE/Documentation/Movies/ct5t.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to scatter the coordinates of one given particle all over the place, so I would begin by writing a simple `struct`:

```
struct Particle { /* coords */ };
```

Then we can make a simple one dimensional array of these `Particles`.

I would probably use a `deque`, because that's the default container, but you may wish to try a `vector`, it's just that 1.000.000 of particles means about a single chunk of a few MBs. It should hold but it might strain your system if this ever grows, while the `deque` will allocate several chunks.

**WARNING**:

As Alexandre C remarked, if you go the `deque` road, refrain from using `operator[]` and prefer to use iteration style. If you really need random access and it's performance sensitive, the `vector` should prove faster.

Comment: Wouldn't `vector` be better as we can reserve the amount of memory using `reserve()` so that no allocation takes place later?

Comment: Hi Matthieu! I agree declaring a struct is usually a good idea. Having structs in STL containers does limit you because you cant modify them in-place (like `particles[i].x += 1`). You'll have to take a particle out of the array, modify it, and copy it back in. If you don't take that into account when writing the code, it could affect performance.

Comment: but *please* don't use operator[] with the deque in a loop

Comment: @jdv: you can of course modify it in place (apart from `set`)! @Alexandre C: good caveat, with a `deque` it's best to use iterators.

Comment: @Naveen: there is fast and there is possible. Requiring a large amount of memory may fail because the memory is too fragmented. If it's possible, it will be faster.

Comment: @All: I can use a `deque` with iterator, from beginning to end, I don't need random access. So the `deque` option seems good to me.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: But if it is possible to allocate a single large amount of memory, will `deque` do it ? Will it play a role in processor caching or things like that ? Does `deque` have other advantages compared to `vector` ?
Thx !

Comment: @Cedric: No the deque will not allocate a single chunk. If you don't need random-access, then all the better: You can easily replace whatever container you tried first and measure the difference. And try `std::vector` first.

Comment: @Cedric H: `deque` allow to add / remove elements at both ends in O(1) while meddling with the front of a `vector` causes the elements to be shuffled (which doesn't matter for small containers). You can think of a `deque` as a queue of arrays of elements.

Comment: @sbi: I was asking for the allocation to know if there can be a difference in processor caching optimizations for example. Any idea ? As you said, if I loop my container with iterators, I can easily replace `vector` by a `deque` later.

Comment: @Cedric: TTBOMK, `std::vector` gives you the most-possible locality. However, modern processors are mean, speculating beasts. I'd not try to second-guess them. Measure. Measure. Measure.

Answer (score 8):

> So is it a good idea to use `std::vector<double>` ?

Usually, a `std::vector` should be the first choice of container. You could use either `std::vector<>::reserve()` or `std::vector<>::resize()` to avoid reallocations while populating the vector. Whether any other container is better can be found by ***measuring***. And only by measuring. But first measure whether anything the container is involved in (populating, accessing elements) is worth optimizing at all.

> If I use a std::vector, should I create a two dimensional array like `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` [...]?

No. IIUC, you are accessing your data per particle, not per row. If that's the case, why not use a `std::vector<particle>`, where `particle` is a struct holding six values? And even if I understood incorrectly, you should rather write a two-dimensional wrapper around a one-dimensional container. Then align your data either in rows or columns - what ever is faster with your access patterns.

> Do you think that Blitz is OK, or is it useless in my case?

I have no practical knowledge about blitz++ and the areas it is used in. But isn't blitz++ all about expression templates to unroll loop operations and optimizing away temporaries when doing matrix manipulations? ICBWT.

Comment: Ok for the `particle` structure. About Blitz: actually what I could do is to use a `particle` structure, which is actually a blitz::Array and instead of performing coordinate by coordinate manipulation, I can then manipulate them directly as a vector, I could then by executed more efficiently. Maybe...

Comment: Neil Butterworth had a very interesting blog post about why `deque` should be the default container while `vector` was to be chosen for C-compatibility. However since he asked to delete his account on SO and I can't remember the address of the blog... I would be hard pressed to point it to you.

Comment: @sbi: yes it is! I am going to bookmark this right away, and here is the article: http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/letter-the-fourth/ it begins with a rant against how we are taught lists in CS class when it's about the least efficient container one can find.

Comment: @Matthieu: Nice, google found me that. Anyway, for now I've only just skimmed through the article, but at the end it says "Your initial choice of data structure should normally be the `std::vector`. This has good overall performance and can be used with legacy code such as the Win32 APIs. If you need to delete (or insert) at the beginning of the structure, (or elsewhere, other than the end) use a `std:;deque` [sic]."

Comment: @sbi: you're right, I apologize for both a faulty memory and not actually re-reading the article myself.

Comment: @Matthieu: Well, you couldn't have re-read it before you knew where to find it. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

The first rule when choosing from containers is to use `std::vector`. Then, only after your code is complete and you can actually measure performance, you can try other containers. But stick to vector first. (And use `reserve()` from the start)

Then, you shouldn't use an `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`. You know the size of your data: it's 6 doubles. No need for it to be dynamic. It is constant and fixed. You can define a struct to hold you particle members (the six doubles), or you can simply typedef it: `typedef double particle[6]`. Then, use a vector of particles: `std::vector<particle>`.

Furthermore, as your program uses the particle data contained in the vector sequentially, you will take advantage of the modern CPU cache read-ahead feature at its best performance.

Comment: Thx ! Do you think there are performance differences between a `struct` containing 6 `double` and a static array of 6 doubles ?

Comment: I'm absolutely certain there is no difference at all, performance wise. There can be some differences on the readability side though.

Answer (score 1):

You could go several ways. But in your case, **don't** declare a`std::vector<std::vector<double> >`. You're allocating a `vector` (and you copy it around) for every 6 doubles. Thats way too costly.

Answer (score 1):

> If you think that this is the best option, would it be possible to wrap this vector in a way that it can be accessed with a index operator defined as other_array[i,j] // same as other_array[6*i+j] without overhead (like function call at each access) ?

(`other_array[i,j]` won't work too well, as i,j employs the comma operator to evaluate the value of "i", then discards that and evaluates and returns "j", so it's equivalent to `other_array[i]`).

You will need to use one of:

```
other_array[i][j]
other_array(i, j)  // if other_array implements operator()(int, int),
                   // but std::vector<> et al don't.
other_array[i].identifier // identifier is a member variable
other_array[i].identifier() // member function getting value
other_array[i].identifier(double) // member function setting value
```

You may or may not prefer to put get_ and set_ or similar on the last two functions should you find them useful, but from your question I think you won't: functions are prefered in APIs between parts of large systems involving many developers, or when the data items may vary and you want the algorithms working on the data to be independent thereof.

So, a good test: if you find yourself writing code like `other_array[i][3]` where you've decided "3" is the double with the speed in it, and `other_array[i][5]` because "5" is the the acceleration, then stop doing that and give them proper identifiers so you can say `other_array[i].speed` and `.acceleration`.  Then other developers can read and understand it, and you're much less likely to make accidental mistakes.  On the other hand, if you are iterating over those 6 elements doing exactly the same things to each, then you probably do want Particle to hold a double[6], or to provide an `operator[](int)`.  There's no problem doing both:

```
struct Particle
{
    double x[6];
    double& speed() { return x[3]; }
    double speed() const { return x[3]; }
    double& acceleration() { return x[5]; }
    ...
};
```

BTW / the reason that `vector<vector<double> >` may be too costly is that each set of 6 doubles will be allocated on the heap, and for fast allocation and deallocation many heap implementations use fixed-size buckets, so your small request will be rounded up t the next size: that may be a significant overhead.  The outside vector will also need to record a extra pointer to that memory.  Further, heap allocation and deallocation is relatively slow - in you're case, you'd only be doing it at startup and shutdown, but there's no particular point in making your program slower for no reason.  Even more importantly, the areas on the heap may just around in memory, so your operator[] may have cache-faults pulling in more distinct memory pages than necessary, slowing the entire program.  Put another way, vectors store elements contiguously, but the pointed-to-vectors may not be contiguous.